# R intersection of lists

Tags: r

I have 2 lists, each with multiple variables (I think this is the correct term).  And I want to find the intersection for each variable.  See the example below:

```
x<-list(A=c(1,2,3),B=c(4,5,6),C=c(7,8,9)) #input
y<-list(A=c(1,3,6,7),B=c(5,7,8),C=c(7,9,10)) #input
xinty<-list(A=c(1,3),B=5,C=c(7,8)) # desired output
```

I have tried the following, but it is obviously wrong.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
xinty<-lapply(x,function(x) intersect(x,y))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intersection of Lists in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630792/intersection-of-lists-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
mapply(intersect, x,y)
```

Comment: Note this will fail if your lists aren't the same length, and it is done by position in the list, and not by name - ie x[[1]] is intersected with y[[1]], not x$A with y$A unless they are in the same order as in your example